# z-index behaves differently in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, z-index

i have the following code

```
#flipper #Front {
    z-index:81;
}
#flipper #Back {
    z-index:80;
}
.face{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.front{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#flipper > * {
    max-width:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}


       <div id='flipper'>
        <div id='Front' class='front face'>
            <img src='images/front.gif'>
        </div>
        <div id='Back' class='back face'>
            <img src='images/back.gif'>
            <a href="/link" title="get in /here/" style="position: relative; top: -100px; display:none;">peek</a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and script

```
/* flip */

function flipOwlly() {
        if (Side=='front') {
                jQuery('#flipper').css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(180deg)');
                jQuery('#flipper').css('-moz-transform','rotateY(180deg)');
                jQuery('#Front').css('z-index','79');
                jQuery('#flipper a[href="/login"]').css('display', 'inline-block');
                Side = 'back';
        } else {
                jQuery('#flipper').css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(360deg)');
                jQuery('#flipper').css('-moz-transform','rotateY(360deg)');
                //setTimeout(jQuery('#Front').css('z-index','81'), 550);
                jQuery('#Front').css('z-index','81');
                owllySide = 'front';
        }
        return false;
}
```

EDITED TO ADD JS CODE

and i have a jquery code to run css animation for flipping the whole #flipper element, and then changing the front z-index to 79 [and back].

my problem is that this displays differently on firefox and chrome.   in firefox, higher z-index number send my image back!  so when the page loads, the logical order is ok, but the back image is on top of the front on....

even IE renders it fine!  whats going on?

Comment: BTW: Why do you flip the elements, if you are using z-index to manipulate the visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i fixed this was kind of workaround, which i really dont like, but it was the only way i could find..

since i have 2 div for each side, i simply 'display:none'-ed the back face one, so even if a browser wrongfully decides to display it, it won't!

Answer (score 2):

Posting your jquery code could help. Anyway, I tested flipping the z-index and it [seems to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/SzwFx/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#flipper").click(function()
    {
        $("#Front").css("z-index", $("#Front").css("z-index") == "79" ? "81" : "79"); 
    });
});
```

However, if you are just trying to toggle between the images, it would be better to [toggle their visibility](http://jsfiddle.net/SzwFx/) rather than their z-indexes:

```
#flipper #Back 
{
    display: none;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#flipper").click(function()
    {                     
        $("#Front").toggle();
        $("#Back").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: nope, im actually animating it for a flip effect. but thats not the problem at all, the flip and the switch work, but the initial z-index value for the top image [81] seems to be lower then its back side [80] , but only on FF..   you can view it on obnoxiousowl dot com - its on the right side, right click it

Comment: Maybe a jsFiddle example of your problem will make it clearer.

Comment: did you perhaps give it a look?